# I installed dual-boot system on my Windows 10 and now can't access the other OS

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

A while ago, I installed Kali Linux on my Windows 10 laptop in order to dual-boot, and than I picked Windows 10 as startup and so it never asks me what to pick at start.  But now I don't know how to start Kali Linux.

For these of asked more info i can give very little amount of info since I dont remember much as well. I installed kali linux on same har drive I use windows by shrinking the hdd into two parts. and at start the PC was asking me what to run, windows or kali and than a while late I picked run Windows on startup on BIOS i guess than it never asked me what to run and kept running windows 10 away and never ask me the option where I can pick eather run kali or windows. Now I would like to run Kali but dont know how I run it. and as much I remember I didnt use GRUB.

Comment: We need more information.  Are Windows and Linux on different partitions of the same drive, or separate drives?  How did you install this (adding Kali to pre-existing Windows)?  Did Kali install GRUB?  Do you never see boot options?  Where and how did you set Windows as the default?  How do you try to access the OS selection?  How did you prepare Kali for UEFI?

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most common issues in dual-booting are:

1. Disabled legacy BIOS option (issue persists on some newer laptops with Win10 pre-installed)
2. Wrong partitions or filesystems

So, give some more spicific info OR refer to Kali Linux forums for support. Here is a related topic from forums.kali.org: [check if the problem is similar to your own](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?29078-Windows-10-Kali-Linux-2-0-Dual-Boot-problems)

Answer (score 0):

When installing Windows after a Linux, Windows "breaks" the Linux boot-manager (GRUB).

The solution is reinstalling GRUB from a live CD/USB, as explained here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/83771/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7